# post data via redirect function in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

Is there ever a way or some tricks to post an array of data or a single variable string data using redirect() function in codeiginter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

when using `redirect` you go from one controller or another by this process all post data are destroyed unless you stored them on a session, here is how i do it

```
$data = array('firstname'=>'fname','lastname'=>'lastname');
// i store data to flashdata
$this->session->set_flashdata('lolwut',$data);
// after storing i redirect it to the controller
redirect('controller/method')
```

so on your redirected controller you can access it via `$this->session->flashdata('lolwut')`
note that i am using `flashdata` not `userdata`, `flashdata` destroys itself on the next process.

read more flashdata here [SESSION CLASS](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the first place why you need post data while redirect :

you can have post function that handle all your code and then redirect after success or failure depends on your usage

```
function method()
{
    //do something
    redirect('path/to/method');
}
```

if you want to have variables passed through other pages you can do this by :

1. Save data into session, `$this->session->set_data($data);` or `$this->set_flashdata($data);` depends on your usage
2. Pass in URL as parameter instead of form submission

hope that helped you someway