# AJAX call to CodeIgniter controller with parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I know how `AJAX` call to `CodeIgniter` is working.

***Edit for suggested answer***

> I tried `redirection` as a possible solution to my problem. I am not asking it as question. I am having problem passing parameter through URL and reusing view containing `ajax post call`. Also I am not aware how to post single value `state_id` which is already part of `new_admission` form.

I am loading `city names` for `state_id` of `branch` dynamically on `$(document).ready()`

When I call `load_city()` from `admission()` it works perfect.

`XHR` for `load_city` goes like:

> localhost/project_folder/controller/load_city

But when I try `edit_admission($studentId)` it loads `admission_view` recursively inside `<div id="city"></div>`.

`XHR` for `load_city` goes like:

> localhost/project_folder/controller/edit_admission/load_city

Here `load_city` is considered as parameter and `edit_admission()` is called recursively.

Controller:

```
public function load_city()
    {
    //load cities to $data from model 
    $this->load->view('city_view', $data);
    }

public function admission()
    {
    //load init data for admission view from model 
    $this->load->view('admission_view', $data);
    }

public function edit_admission($studentId)
    {
    //load init data for admission view from model 
    $this->load->view('admission_view', $data);

    }
```

`AJAX` code:

```
function get_city() {
    var parameters = {}; //instantiate the array
    parameters['state_id'] = state_id;

    $('#divcity').load('load_city', parameters, function (data) {
        $('#city').combobox();
        //code
    });

};
```

`load_city` view:

```
<?php
    echo '<select class="'.'form-control chzn-select col-lg-8 required'.'" id="'.'city'.'" name="'.'city'.'">';
    echo '<option></option>';
    foreach ($init_city['city_names'] as $row)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row->city_id.'">' .$row->city_name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

`admission_view`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">City</label>

    <div class="col-lg-8" id="divcity" name="divcity"></div>
</div>
```

***I tried***

```
public function edit_admission($studentId)
    {
    if(intval($studentId) > 0){
        //load init data for admission view from model
        $this->load->view('admission_view', $data);
    } else if($studentId == 'load_city'){
        //not passing post data to load_city()
        redirect('branch/load_city');
    }

}
```

Above code is not passing post data to `load_city()`.

Also, I tried adding bellow code in `routes.php`

```
$route['edit_admission/load_city'] = 'load_city';
```

I did not get any success in both cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [post data via redirect function in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241124/post-data-via-redirect-function-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Your question is really poorly structured and confusing to me. Anyway, I think you need to take another look at the basic CI documentation. To call a method with parameters, you should use an url like `controller/function/param1/param2`, DON'T pass them through post if you want it to work like this. If you do want to use post, remove the parameter of your function and add `$studentId = $this->input->post('state_id')`. Again, I don't understand what the problem is. Please reword http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @825K Thanks for pointing out! As mentioned in question, I thought redirecting will be one solution. It is not better in my case as I have to change existing working code.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn I already tried what you are suggesting. You are correct. I am having problem passing parameter through URL and reusing view containing ajax post call. Also I am not aware how to post single value state_id which is already part of new_admission form.