# how to extract data from array in php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following function in my main controller

```
 public function Main_Search_Form()
       {
           $subs_id      = $this->input->post('subs_id'); 
           $town_id      = $this->input->post('town_id'); 
           $account_type = $this->input->post('account_type'); 
           $postcode     = $this->input->post('postcode');

           $data = array("account_type"  =>$account_type,
                         "subs_id"       =>$subs_id,
                         "town_id"       =>$town_id,
                         "postcode"      =>$postcode
                        );

           if($account_type == 'TUTOR')
           {
            redirect(base_url() . 'Tutor_Controller/Tutor_Search_Result',$data);   
           } 

           if($account_type == 'STUDENT')
           {
            redirect(base_url() . 'Student_Controller/Student_Search_Result',$data);   
           } 

}
```

I first check if the value of the $account_type is TUTOR or STUDENT. If it is TUTOR, I want to call another function which is in 'Tutor_Controller' file. My question is how can I get the values of the variables which I am sending through the array 'data' in the Tutor_Search_Result function.

Comment: what actually you want to do? just a basic redirect? or you want to render something? 

anyway, it seems you are recieving a post request - which is intended to create/update/delete (at least it was) a resource. where are you handling resource creation/manipulation?

Comment: See this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241124/post-data-via-redirect-function-in-codeigniter) for how to go about passing data along with a redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can use CodeIgniter's flashdata feature, which sends data to the next request:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

**Usage:**

```
To send data: 

$this->session->set_flashdata('acc_data', json_encode($data));
```

and

```
To read data:

$_SESSION['acc_data'];
```